# firebase cloud function "RequestError: Error: Invalid protocol: xxx.xx."

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-functions

I implemented a firebase cloudfunction that index data for searching using elasticsearch. But I am not sure with this error `RequestError: Error: Invalid protocol:` on cloudfunction log.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: thanks @RenaudTarnec i have resolved the issue. I figured out that lack param or args on my request.

Comment: Cool! You may delete your question, since it does not detail very much the problem nor the solution.